# Load Textures in open gl

Tags: opengl, textures

We can't manage to add a texture in open gl.

Here our code to make a simple black/white cases texture:

```
 GLuint tex;//before the main function
```

then in the main:

```
glGenTextures(1, &tex);

float pixels[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

and then in the draw method we apply it in the following way

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(0, 1);     glVertex3d(0, -0.1, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(0, 0);     glVertex3d(50, -0.1, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(1, 1);     glVertex3d(50, -0.1, 50);
    glTexCoord2d(1, 1);     glVertex3d(0, -0.1, 50);
glEnd();
```

We want to apply this texture simple on the ground of the scene. Are we missing something?

Comment: Have you `glEnabled` textures?

Comment: Yes, in the second part of the code at the end is the `_glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

Comment: You never say what you're seeing instead of your texture.  [White quad](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture)?

Comment: I see the last color used on other object I draw on the scene.

Comment: Ah, the 'ole default `GL_MODULATE` + incomplete texture then.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand this answer ('ole..?) And I don't know GL_MODULATE...

Answer (score 1):

- [Upload a complete set of mipmaps or set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture)
- [Set `GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml) to `GL_DECAL` instead of the default `GL_MODULATE` or `glColor3ub(255, 255, 255)` before rendering your quad.

All together:

```
// http://glew.sourceforge.net/
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint tex = 0;
void init()
{
    // upload texture
    glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );
    float pixels[] =
    {
        1, 0, 0,    0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 1,    1, 1, 1,
    };
    glTexImage2D
        (
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 
        GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0,
        GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels
        );

    // configure texture unit
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + 0 );
    glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    // select texture unit & enable it
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + 0 );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i( 0, 0 );     glVertex2i( -1, -1 );
        glTexCoord2i( 1, 0 );     glVertex2i(  1, -1 );
        glTexCoord2i( 1, 1 );     glVertex2i(  1,  1 );
        glTexCoord2i( 0, 1 );     glVertex2i( -1,  1 );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glewInit();
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well I can define the texture like the following, but what is a set of mipmaps? I most exemples I found there isn't anything like that.   What I changed so far... (in the texture declaration) `glGenTextures(1, &tex);
 
 float pixels[] = {
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
 };
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
 glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
 glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL); ` but it's still the other color... and where is to put the GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE ?

Comment: Looks great but I don't have a file named glew.h to include, and the following function arren't defined, included: glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+0) And CL_CAMP_TO_EDGE... is this another version of open gl?

Comment: [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) is an [extension loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: I don't have the rights to use other libraries then the glut.h for this project, it's a statement of our professor... any ideas? And my surface is drawed with point with 3 coordinates. Does this have any influence...

Comment: I finally managed to add the texture on the surface. Thanks a lot for your help, just one thing.: The colors of the other objects seem influenced by the fact of applying a texture. How can I change that? (do I have to disable it after applying it?)

Comment: "do I have to disable it after applying it?"  If you want to render un-textured geometry, yes.

Comment: false alert, anything is fine now. Great support from you, thanks.